# Delphi: How I change the ITask's priority?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, task

I have some low-priority tasks that are working in background, I dont care about how fast they are executed, but sometimes there is a single task that must be executed as fast as possible. How i do that?

```
for k:=1 to 100 do begin 
  Orders[k] := TTask.Create(NewOrder,NewOrder.DoTheJob);
  Orders[k].Start;
end;
......
FastOrder := TTask.Create(NewOrder,NewOrder.DoTheJob);
FastOrder.Start; // I want this task to be executed ASAP, 
    //but actually it waits unpredictable time until there is a free slot
    // in task's queue or so. 
    //It can delay up to 1 minute depending on how many reqular tasks i have
```

Comment: Create another threadpool and feed fastorder tasks into that one. @RemyLebeau explained that earlier, [Delphi 10: Correct way to run tasks simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068997/576719). `If you want more control over the thread pooling, you have to create a TThreadPool object, set its MinWorkerThreads and MaxWorkerThreads properties as desired, and then pass that object to one of the TTask constructors that has an APool input parameter.`

Answer (score -2):

Use TThread.createAnonymousThread instead of TTask